# How can i start a background service with flutter when device boot

Tags: android, flutter, native, background-service

I want listen a websocket from my flutter app even though the app is not open. I found this package for start a background service: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service
This package works fine but it requires that once run the app for start the service. I want the service to run automatically when device boots even if the user don't start the application.

How can i do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hoping to restart a running service after reboot